# How to remove a file after the request

Tags: java, quarkus

I'm creating files during a request. Since they are no more needed after the request I want to remove them from the filesystem.

In RestEasy there were `Cleanables`:

```
File file = new File();
Cleanables cleanables = ResteasyProviderFactory.getContextData(Cleanables.class);
cleanables.addCleanable(file); // removes the file after the request
```

Is there something similar in Quarkus with extension `resteasy-reactive`?

Comment: Which Quarkus extension are you using?

Comment: @geoand I'm using 'resteasy-reactive'. Created a project with 'quarkus create app org.acme:getting-started --extension='resteasy-reactive''. Added it to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RESTEasy Reactive has `io.quarkus.resteasy.reactive.server.Closer` which you would use like this:

```
    @GET
    public Response get(@Context Closer closer) {
        File file = new File();  
        closer.add(() -> file.delete());
        return RestResponse.ok("something");
    }
```